# Convert string to object by splitting the string javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I need to convert the full strings to array, object combination.
Example,

```
let string = {'user-0-residences-0-pincode': 678987};

// Expecting output will be
{
  user: [
    {
      residences: [
        {
          pincode: 678987
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: what does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, you can try the following code

```js
 let string = { "user-0-residences-0-pincode": 678987 };
  let output = null, temp;
  Object.keys(string)[0]
    .split("-0-")
    .reverse()
    .forEach(val => {
      if (output === null) {
        output = {};
        output[val] = Object.values(string)[0];
      } else {
        temp = [];
        temp.push(output);
        output = {}
        output[val] = temp;
      }
    });
    console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You save my day.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are doing, but it seems like you are using '-0-' as a delimiter.  Work with something like this.

```
let string = {'user-0-residences-0-pincode': 678987};
let result = []
for (str in string) {
    result.push(str.split('-0-'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> // Expecting output will be {   user: [
>       {
>         residences: [
>           {
>             pincode: 678987
>           }]
>       }] }

Your result does not look right...

I think you wanted to parse a string: `"user-0-residences-0-pincode-678987"`

You can do so:

```js
var string = "user-0-residences-0-pincode-678987";
var arr = string.split("-");
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
 result[arr[i]] = arr[i + 1];
}
console.log(result);
```